# Sharepoint Designer 2013 custom javascript code is ignored

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Using Sharepoint Designer 2013. Adding simple javascript code inside `<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">` tag. When I do View Source, js code I placed is not shown. What would be wrong?

Here it is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.01/jquery.SPServices.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
    relationshipList: "Kisiler",
    relationshipListParentColumn: "Firma",
    relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
    relationshipListSortColumn: "Title",
    parentColumn: "Firma",
    childColumn: "Sorumlu"
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Where are you placing your JS code?  Normally, you place it right before the </asp> tag that closes Main.  Not sure if that matters, it's just a convention I have never strayed from, so I'm not sure if that's the culprit.

Comment: Please share how are you adding your js file and where are you deploying your JS file?

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: Make sure you have checked-in / published the page in SP Designer